# Automating the creation of a virtual machine from a template

Tags: vhd, virtual-machines

What's the best way to go about creating a (Virtual PC/Server) virtual machine from a VHD template? Specifically, what's the best way to change the name of a virtual PC so that it is unique on a network, preferably without loading the the VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reseal the VM with sysprep before you create the template. this will make every VM derived from the sysprepped template unique

Comment: just leave the computername field empty in the sysprep file n you'll be able to set the name @ the minisetup